# How to import a widget package in Mendix?

Tags: mendix

I want to add [Microflow Timer](https://appstore.home.mendix.com/link/app/27/) in my application. When I click download button, widget was not placed in my app project structure as it was mentioned in the official documentation [here](https://docs.mendix.com/developerportal/app-store/app-store-content#widget).. Then I paced that in widget folder of my app by following [this](https://forum.mendixcloud.com/link/questions/88764) answer.

This is where I have placed my widget.

[image]

still its not listed under add-on widget when click add widget in data-view. Here are screen-shots.

[image]

Select widget Screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to press <kbd>F4</kbd> in the Modeler - it will synchronize the widgets folder with your Model. Then, the widget will be available.

> **Synchronize Project Directory**
>
> If necessary, this action creates folders inside the project directory (resources, widgets, theme, etc.). It also reads the widget packages that are currently inside the widgets folders. For example, if you add widgets to the widgets folder, you needs to synchronize the project directory for them to appear in the form toolbox.

([source](https://docs.mendix.com/refguide/desktop-modeler-overview))